# mmap flag MAP_UNINITIALIZED not defined

Tags: linux, mmap

mmap() docs mentions flag MAP_UNINITIALIZED, but the flag doesn't seem to be defined.
Tried on Centos7, and Xenial, neither distro has the flag defined in `sys/mman.h` as alleged.
Astonishingly, the internet doesn't seem to be aware of this. What's the story?

Edit: I understand from the docs that the flag is only honoured on embedded or low-security devices, but that doesn't mean the flag shouldn't be defined... How do you use it in portable code? Google has revealed code where it is defined as `0` in cases where not supported, except in my cases it's not defined at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to understand what to do about the fact that `#include <sys/mman.h>` does not define `MAP_UNINITIALIZED`, it is helpful to understand how the interface to the kernel is defined.

To build a kernel module, you will need the kernel headers used to build the kernel for the exact version of the kernel for which you wish to build the module.  As you wish to run in userspace, you won't need these.

The headers that define the kernel API for userspace are largely in `/usr/include/linux` and `/usr/include/asm` (see [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/headers_install.txt) for how they are generated).  One of the more important consumers of these headers is the C standard library, *e.g.*, `glibc`, which must be built against some version of these headers.  Since the linux kernel API is backwards compatible, you may have a glibc (or other library implementation) built against an older version of these headers than the kernel you are running.  I'm by no means an expert on how all the various distros distribute glibc, but it is my impression that the kernel headers defining its userspace API are generally the version that glibc has been built against.

Finally, glibc defines its API through headers also installed under `/usr/include` such as `/usr/include/sys`.  I don't know exactly what, if any, backward or forward compatibility is provided for applications built with older or newer glibc headers, but I'm guessing that the library .so version number gets bumped when backward comparability would be broken.

So now we can understand your problem to be that the glibc headers don't actually define `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` for the distros/versions that you tried.

However, the linux kernel API has exposed `MAP_UNINITIALIZED`, as [this patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/7149071/) demonstrates.  If the glibc headers don't define it for you, you can use the linux kernel API headers and `#include <linux/mman.h>` if this defines it.  Note that you will still need to `#include <sys/mman.h>` in order to get the prototype for mmap, among other things.

If your linux kernel API headers don't define `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` but you have a kernel version that implements it, you can define it yourself:

```
 #define MAP_UNINITIALIZED 0x4000000
```

You don't have to worry that you are effectively using "newer" headers than your glibc was built with, because the glibc implementation of `mmap` is very thin:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sysdep.h>

#ifndef MMAP_PAGE_SHIFT
#define MMAP_PAGE_SHIFT 12
#endif

__ptr_t
__mmap (__ptr_t addr, size_t len, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset)
{
  if (offset & ((1 << MMAP_PAGE_SHIFT) - 1))
    {
      __set_errno (EINVAL);
      return MAP_FAILED;
    }
  return (__ptr_t) INLINE_SYSCALL (mmap2, 6, addr, len, prot, flags, fd,
                                   offset >> MMAP_PAGE_SHIFT);
}

weak_alias (__mmap, mmap)
```

It is just passing your flags straight through to the kernel.

Comment: Side question: what is `<linux/mman.h>` as opposed to `<sys/mman.h>`?

Comment: That's really comprehensive, thanks!
Out of curiosity, what would happen if I define `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` myself, and then pass that flag to an older kernel that doesn't have support fot the flag? Will it be ignored, or will it produce some error? (The docs say "if the flag is not supported, it is ignored", does that go too for older kernels?)

Comment: @ManuEvans I can't know without looking at all prior kernels, and in general the linux kernel only provides backward compatibility, not forward.  If you wanted to be careful, use something like [`uname`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/uname) to verify the kernel is >= 2.6.33 before using it.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel normally needs to clear the memory, to protect the privacy of both kernel space and other process' memory.

Continue reading:

> This flag is honored only if the kernel was configured with the  CONFIG_MMAP_ALLOW_UNINITIALIZED option. Because of the security implications, that option is normally enabled only on embedded devices  (i.e., devices where one has complete control of the contents of user memory).

Comment: Right, I understand, but on embedded, it is supported.. it said "flag is honoured", which I read, "is defined, but only does anything if kernel is built as such". If the flag isn't defined, I'm not sure how you're supposed to write portable code that's optimised appropriately for embedded devices?

Comment: Using the memory uninitialized doesn't benefit so much, since the device has enough power to run the Linux kernel. (Some boards doesn't have enough memory to split kernel and user space.)

Comment: I know why to and not to use this flag... The only question here is, why is `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` not defined in the header as documented?

Comment: "Using the memory uninitialized doesn't benefit so much" I have worked on an (embedded) system where it had a huge performance impact. Clearing pages on first map was taking a long time. Doesn't seem like it should have... but it was.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi why does CONFIG_MMAP_ALLOW_UNINITIALIZED require MMU to be disabled in the kernel config? I am interested in using this feature and I don't want to disable MMU as it has a lot of other consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Uninitialized memory allocation is only possible on CPUs without MMU and if `CONFIG_MMAP_ALLOW_UNINITIALIZED` is enabled.

Glibc doesn't support CPUs without MMU.

This is the answer why glibc doesn't declare `MAP_UNINITIALIZED`.

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question; why isn't it declared as zero on systems where not supported so code is portable?

Comment: @ManuEvans I think the same way as you. But what I said is the reason why it's not defined. You can read it here https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31430