# Do I have to add the length of the mapping to a pointer returned by mmap with the MAP_GROWSDOWN and MAP_STACK flags?

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I'm creating a simple stack for an a.out loader and I've come up with this:

```
stack = (char *)mmap(NULL,
                     65535,
                     PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                     MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_STACK |
                       MAP_GROWSDOWN | MAP_UNINITIALIZED |
                       MAP_ANONYMOUS,
                     -1,
                     0);
```

However, I'm not sure about this.

Do I have to add `65535` (the size of the mapping) to the resulting pointer before I move it to the stack pointer because I used the `MAP_STACK` and `MAP_GROWSDOWN` flags? Or can I just use it as it is?

The documentation for this hasn't been very clear, and I haven't been able to find anything when searching the Internet.

Specifically, this (from mmap(2)) confuses me:

> The return address is one page lower than the memory area that is actually created in the process's virtual address space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you have to add 65536 to the resulting pointer.   Note, not 65535.   Most architectures implement push(x) as *--sp = x; so having the sp *above* the stack is ok to start with.   More importantly it has to be aligned, and 65535 is not.
2. The documentation appears to be wrong.   I think it intends "is one page *higher* than the...".   That better aligns with the source implementation, and the result of the little sample program below:

---

```
  #include <signal.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <sys/mman.h>

  volatile int sp;

  void segv(int signo) {
          char buf[80];
          int n = snprintf(buf, 80, "(%d): sp = %#x\n", signo, sp);
          write(1, buf, n);
           _exit(1);
  }

  int main(void) {
          int N = 65535;
          signal(SIGSEGV, segv);
          signal(SIGBUS, segv);
          char *stack = (char *)mmap(NULL,
                       N,
                       PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                       MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_STACK |
                         MAP_GROWSDOWN | /*MAP_UNINITIALIZED |*/
                         MAP_ANONYMOUS,
                       -1,
                       0);
          printf("stack %p\n", stack);
          for (sp = 0; sp < N; sp += 4096) {
                  if (stack[sp]) {
                          printf("stack[%d] = %x\n", sp, stack[sp]);
                  }
          }
          for (sp = 0; sp > -N; sp -= 4096) {
                  if (stack[sp]) {
                          printf("stack[%d] = %x\n", sp, stack[sp]);
                  }
          }
          return 0;
  }
```

which prints out:

```
$ ./a.out
stack 0x7f805c5fb000
(11): sp = -4096
```

on my system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux u2 4.15.0-42-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 19:32:57 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Why'd you comment out `MAP_UNINITIALIZED`?

Comment: My linux didn’t have that enabled [ see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784442/mmap-flag-map-uninitialized-not-defined last comment ]

Comment: Really? I have it enabled on 3.18 (I use `asm/mman.h` though).

Comment: `/usr/local/include/asm-generic/mman-common.h: # define MAP_UNINITIALIZED 0x4000000       /* For anonymous mmap, memory could be uninitialized */`

Comment: Its a security thing, which is why I guess ubuntu turns it down.   Note that glibc can filter your options down, so being able to spec; if you run it as strace -e trace=mmap ./a.out, you might not see your option in the args.